# Server Error Error: middleware is not a function WHEN I use Redux in NEXTJS

Tags: next.js, redux, redux-thunk

When I run program, it appears **error "Server Error Error: middleware is not a function".**
I don't know why it happened. How can I fix this error?
This is my code in **store.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from '@redux-devtools/extension'

const reducer = combineReducers({})

const initialState = {}

const middleware = [thunk]

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
)

export default store
```

I want to know why it appears that error and How I can fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a global store server-side with next.js. Please read (and try to follow) https://redux.js.org/usage/nextjs

Comment: Does it make any sense to say "You can't have a global store server-side with next.js" and then link to the documentation that explains how to setup and use a Redux store in Next.js?  ‍♂️ Maybe provide a bit more context here so the answer stands on it's own without the need to go to a 3rd-party site to get the required information to understand your statement.

Comment: @DrewReese The answer standing on it's own would require me to simply copy-paste from the linked docs page, which addresses OP's exact use case.